# how to retrieve and manipulate data from Vuex store

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I try to make door configurator using Vue.

First of all I put array of components from DB into Vuex store `.get('/api/furnitura')`
This gives me array with all components available for different type of doors.
Hinges, handles, locks etc.
And then I am going to have few Vue components. Each component is one configurator of specific door type.

What I found in Vue documentation is that it is possible to access Vuex store variables from each point of the application like that

```
    computed: {
      getFurnitura(){
         return this.$store.state.furnitura.all
      }
    },
```

But I want to manipulate store variables in Vue.
Something like that
`Take all from this.$store.state.furnitura.all where type=SOMETYPE and type=ANOTHERTYPE`

For one calculator I want retrieve from **this.$store.state.furnitura.all** only few type of hinges and handles. For another something different.
Then I want to use them in select fields. For example in DB I have about 50 hinges in DB and for one type of door I need to retrieve only 5, for another only 3 and so on.
Having API call for every select field seems not reasonable for me

```
<select name="hinge_selected" v-model="hinge_selected">
<option v-for="option in hinges" :value="option">
  {{ option.name }}
</option>
</select>

<select name="handle_selected" v-model="handle_selected">
<option v-for="option in handles" :value="option">
  {{ option.name }}
</option>
</select>

and so on
```

Here is my code now

**resources\js\app.js**

```
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
window.Vue = require('vue');
import store from './store';
Vue.component('modalform', require('./components/modalform.vue').default);
Vue.component('calc-dush-door', require('./components/calculators/dush-door.vue').default);
Vue.component('calc-interior-door', require('./components/calculators/interior-door.vue').default);
Vue.component('calc-sliding-door', require('./components/calculators/sliding-door.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    data: {    },
    directives: {   },
    computed: {
      getFurnitura(){
         return this.$store.state.furnitura.all
      }
    },

    methods: {   },

    mounted() {
        console.log("Vue ROOT instance mounted");
        this.$store.dispatch('furnitura/getFurnitura');
    }
});
```

**resources\js\store\index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import furnitura from './modules/glass';
import furnitura from './modules/furnitura';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    glass,
    furnitura
  }
});
```

**resources\js\store\modules\furnitura.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const state = {
  all: []
};
 
const getters = {  };
 
const mutations = {
  SET_FURNITURA (state, furnitura) {
    state.all = furnitura;
  }
};

const actions = {
  getFurnitura (context) {
    axios
      .get('/api/furnitura') // this gives me result of Furnitura::all();
      .then(response => {
        context.commit('SET_FURNITURA', response.data.records)
      });
  }
};

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
};
```

**resources\js\store\components\calculators\sliding-door.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
<select name="hinge_selected" v-model="hinge_selected">
<option v-for="option in hinges" :value="option">
  {{ option.name }}
</option>
</select>

<select name="handle_selected" v-model="handle_selected">
<option v-for="option in handles" :value="option">
  {{ option.name }}
</option>
</select>

</div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        name: "SlidingDoorCalc",

        data: function () {
          return {
            width: 600,
            height: 2000,
            hinge_selected: [],
            handle_selected: [],
          }
        },


        computed: {     
          getFurnitura(){
             return this.$store.state.furnitura.all
          }
        },

        methods: {        },
        mounted() {        },

    }
</script>
```

Comment: _"Take all from `this.$store.state.furnitura.all` where `type=SOMETYPE` and `type=ANOTHERTYPE`"_  sounds like a case for getters. See https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular component methods, as in:

```
{
    // ...
    methods: {
        getHinges(filterParameter1, filterParameter2) {
            // do your filtering and sorting on
            // this.$store.state.furnitura.all
        },
        getHandles(filterParameter1) {
            // same as with getHinges
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your component, you call it as:

```
<select name="hinge_selected" v-model="hinge_selected">
    <option v-for="option in getHinges('some_parameter')" :value="option">
        {{ option.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

If you want to use the same filtering logic in multiple methods, use [method-style-access Vuex getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access), as in:

```
getters: {
    // ...
    getHinges: (state) => (filterParameter1, filterParameter2) => {
        // filter your state.furnitura.all here
    }
}
```

and call such getters in your component methods:

```
{
    // ...
    methods: {
        getHinges(filterParameter1, filterParameter2) {
            return this.$store.getters.getHinges(filterParameter1, filterParameter2);
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand how to make getter working. I did like it is described with todos on vuejs.org, but it is not working.In Vue devtools I see getters > furnitura > getFurnituraById:ƒ (id) and no results. ` const state = {
  furnituraitems: []
};
 
const getters = {
  getFurnituraById: state => id => {
    return state.furnituraitems.find(furnituraitem => furnituraitem.id === id);
  },
};`

Comment: You need to call the getter from a method in a component, and then call that method in your template. See the last snippet in my answer.

Comment: I did that, but I have empty select field. And to me it is obvious that if I have nothing in getter I cannot expect to see something in template

Comment: https://bypyrussia-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/popov_bypy_ru/EX8WGxh0QvBKp3Fyd2BhaxYB_UrYiZZSI5STvR_UUSYqSQ?e=BXgb4R

Comment: At the screenshot above you can see that getter getFurnituraById has no result inside

Comment: then in DoorCalc component I do like on screenshot below

Comment: https://bypyrussia-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/popov_bypy_ru/EYGuVPQnXlpKuqiOePw3bJAB_0f31wS94EvepO5kVHxOCw?e=S1agjn

Comment: and select field is empty - I don't see inside result of getFurnitura() method

Comment: 1. Do you see `furnituraitems` in your Vuex state in DevTools? 2. If yes, try to change `===` to `==` in getFurnituraById.